# AVAssetDownloadURLSession memory leak

Tags: objective-c, avasset

I used AVAssetDownloadURLSession to do background download.
Everything worked fine but I always get memory leak from delegate.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuraton = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:url];

AVAssetDownloadURLSession *downloadSession = [AVAssetDownloadURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuraton
                                                                           assetDownloadDelegate:self
                                                                                   delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue];

[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setObject:@"some obj"
                                        forKey:url];

NSURL *downloadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:downloadUrl
                                            options:nil];
AVAssetDownloadTask *downloadTask = [downloadSession assetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset:asset
                                                                        assetTitle:@"SomeTitle"
                                                                  assetArtworkData:nil
                                                                           options:nil];
[downloadTask resume];
```

like

> [__NSCFBackgroundAVAssetDownloadTask _onqueue_didLoadTimeRange:totalTimeRangesLoaded:timeRangeExpectedToLoad:]
>
> [__NSCFBackgroundAVAssetDownloadTask _onqueue_didResolveMediaSelectionPropertyList:]

and I can't find some information about my memory leaks.
Any help?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: @RoiMulia not yet, maybe this method is still not so much used? or just no one care.

Answer (score 0):

You must call -invalidate on downloadSession when you're finished with it.